# I'm getting a recursive error [RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object] - but my code is iterative -- or is it?

Tags: python, loops, selenium, recursion, iteration

I'm getting a recursive error:

> RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python
>   object

But my code is iterative...or is it? I thought it was, based on documentation (here, for example: http://www.pythonlearn.com/html-008/cfbook006.html). I've been reading on how to change an algorithm/code from recursive to iterative (e.g., http://blog.moertel.com/posts/2013-05-11-recursive-to-iterative.html) but I just don't see how it is recursive in the first place.

This code goes to a website, does a search and returns about 122 pages of results. It then clicks through each results page and gathers the links. Then it is meant to click on each link and scrape the text/html from each one.

The code runs beautifully until it gets to the final for loop: `for url in article_urls:`. It will capture and store (on dropbox) just over 200 shtml pages before it returns the error.

The puzzle I'm trying to solve is: how do I avoid getting this error?

Here is the code:

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

def isReady(browser):
    return browser.execute_script("return document.readyState") == "complete"

def waitUntilReady(browser):
    if not isReady(browser):
        waitUntilReady(browser)

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.usprwire.com/cgi-bin/news/search.cgi')

# make a search
query = WebDriverWait(browser, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "query")))
query.send_keys('"test"')
submit = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Search']")
submit.click()
numarticles = 0

# grab article urls
npages = 1
article_urls = []
for page in range(1, npages + 1):
    article_urls += [elm.get_attribute("href") for elm in browser.find_elements_by_class_name('category_links')]
    if page <= 121: #click to the next page
        browser.find_element_by_link_text('[>>]').click()
    if page == 122: #last page in search results, so no '[>>]'' to click on. Move on to next steps.
        continue



# iterate over urls and save the HTML source
for url in article_urls:
    browser.get(url)
    waitUntilReady(browser)
    numarticles = numarticles+1
    title = browser.current_url.split("/")[-1]
    with open('/Users/My/Dropbox/File/Place/'+str(numarticles)+str(title), 'w') as fw:
        fw.write(browser.page_source.encode('utf-8'))

Many thanks in advance for any input.

Comment: You don't even have any function definitions here, much less any recursive ones. So, presumably the exception is either coming from a function in a library you're using, or a function that you wrote that you didn't show us. If you actually showed us the full exception, with traceback, the answer it would be obvious; without that, it's impossible to even guess unless someone happens to know how all of those functions are implemented.

Comment: @abarnert Okay! I've tried many things since the original error. I'll run it again and get the traceback and post it. brb.

Comment: Can you show us `waitUntilReady` code?

Comment: I just added everything else. The full file is up there now. Is that what you were asking for @alexanderlukanin13 ?

Comment: This demonstrates why the traceback is important: it almost certainly includes `waitUntilReady` 999 times in a row. Even if that doesn't mean anything to _you_, it would tell everyone else that's where the problem is, and we'd know which function to ask you to show us.

Comment: @abarnert You are so right. Lesson learned. Since I am new, this is very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously, your `waitUntilReady` goes into infinite recursion, calling itself.

You should change it to something like this:

```
while not isReady(browser):
    time.sleep(1)
```

Waiting for page to completely load in Selenium is not as obvious as it seems, you can read more in [Harry J.W. Percival's article](http://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/how-to-get-selenium-to-wait-for-page-load-after-a-click.html)

Comment: Please accept the most helpful answer. If you can't choose, flip a coin :-)

Comment: Ha! Can I only choose one??? :-) Also, I'm trying to import `time` and `sleep`. So is not working quite yet.

Comment: "There can be only one!" (c)

Comment: @praroh1 was the first to answer, and I was the guy who first pointed at `waitUntilReady`. Decision is up to you, but if your question is answered, please mark the correct answer (any of them) for the sake of other people who may stumble upon the same error in the future.

Comment: I for sure will. I will also clean up my comments and put the final solution up when I get there. Thank you again for your speedy assistance.

Comment: No need to further edit your post, question is complete and answers are clear.

Comment: As a final note: I added import time to the front matter. I then edited the original code to run 'for url in article_urls:' then `browswer.get(url)` then `while not isReady(browser):` then `time.sleep(1)`. Runs like a dream. Many thanks to both @alexanderlukanin13 and @praroh1. They are both correct.

Answer (score 2):

waitUntilReady is a recursive function! It's likely to be called many times, especially if you have a slow connection.

Here's a possible workaround:

```
def waitUntilReady():
    while not isReady():
        time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Ah! Arg! Is a sleep function then recursive as well?

Comment: No, sleep isn't recursive.

Comment: @Christine: If you really want a non-recursive version of what you originally wrote, `while not isReady(): pass` will do it. The `sleep` is just to avoid eating up 100% of your CPU time for no benefit while waiting for that to happen; it doesn't change the logic.

Comment: Thank you so much praroh--you and alex came back with the same suggestion--trying it now.